# trouble with data from a JSON file

Tags: android, json

why the data that I put on my .json doesn't work on my native android app, I'm making an app that shows animals with images and info about them and I am following a youtube tutorial  but the one that the dude uses it work perfectly but mine doesn't.
am I not making the right steps to put the info correctly?
whats a better way to pull info from a json?

I simply don't know.

this is my json format for tests:

https://gist.githubusercontent.com/fernandopuma/d33dffc07c9dfec267ff2029e79ad125/raw/fff8018e890d34b690bfaeda630249917dd2bc42/galeria.json

and this is the other:

https://gist.githubusercontent.com/draskomikic/372a8ca88d6d88ec2e45/raw/e95badd14bf24abc1b7a6dfdf4a8070515650eca

and in the project this is the line where it supose to show the work in the app, it is in the file of values/strings.xml

```
<string name="gallery_feed">https://gist.githubusercontent.com/draskomikic/372a8ca88d6d88ec2e45/raw/e95badd14bf24abc1b7a6dfdf4a8070515650eca</string>
```

I'll apreciate some opinions

thanks!!

Comment: First of all, you need to define for us what you mean by "doesn't work"...do you get an error message? unexpected behavior? both? If it's an error message, please show it to us. If it's unexpected behavior, please tell us what the expected behavior and the actual behavior are. Also, please show us the code that you are using to parse the JSON.
All of that said, you do realize that the 'galeria.json' file's format doesn't match the other two?

Answer (score 0):

Here are some thoughts: 
1. Use jsonschema2pojo website to create Java classes from JSON
2. Add them to the project
3. Fix current JSON formatting, for example in galeria.json you have an extra comma in the end that is not supposed to be there
4. Add gson-2.7.jar library to the project 
5. Use similar snippet to convert JSON into you Java objects

```
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = you_json_string_with_lots_of_objects;
    Type type = new TypeToken<List<Your_Animal_Object>>() {
    }.getType();

    List<Your_Animal_Object> list = gson.fromJson(json, type);
```

6. You will get a list of animal objects

Comment: Hello Max, how do I add the gson2-7.jar to the project??

Comment: FIle->Project Structure->Your app module-> Dependencies->Add->Library Dependency and search for gson, last version is 2.8.0